# Please explain the error in detail and how should i resolve it

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file = pd.read_csv('Metro_Interstate_Traffic_Volume.csv')
file
holiday temp    rain_1h snow_1h clouds_all  weather_main    weather_description date_time   traffic_volume
0   None    288.28  0.00    0.0 40  Clouds  scattered clouds    02-10-2012 09:00    5545
1   None    289.36  0.00    0.0 75  Clouds  broken clouds   02-10-2012 10:00    4516
2   None    289.58  0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 02-10-2012 11:00    4767
3   None    290.13  0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 02-10-2012 12:00    5026
4   None    291.14  0.00    0.0 75  Clouds  broken clouds   02-10-2012 13:00    4918
5   None    291.72  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    02-10-2012 14:00    5181
6   None    293.17  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    02-10-2012 15:00    5584
7   None    293.86  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    02-10-2012 16:00    6015
8   None    294.14  0.00    0.0 20  Clouds  few clouds  02-10-2012 17:00    5791
9   None    293.1   0.00    0.0 20  Clouds  few clouds  02-10-2012 18:00    4770
10  None    290.97  0.00    0.0 20  Clouds  few clouds  02-10-2012 19:00    3539
11  None    289.38  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    02-10-2012 20:00    2784
12  None    288.61  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    02-10-2012 21:00    2361
13  None    NaN 0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    02-10-2012 22:00    1529
14  None    285.45  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    02-10-2012 23:00    963
15  None    284.63  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    03-10-2012 00:00    506
16  None    283.47  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    03-10-2012 01:00    321
17  None    281.18  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    03-10-2012 02:00    273
18  None    281.09  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    03-10-2012 03:00    367
19  None    NaN 0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    03-10-2012 04:00    814
20  None    278.62  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    03-10-2012 05:00    2718
21  None    278.23  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    03-10-2012 06:00    5673
22  None    278.12  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    03-10-2012 08:00    6511
23  None    282.48  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    03-10-2012 09:00    5471
24  None    291.97  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    03-10-2012 12:00    5097
25  None    293.23  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    03-10-2012 13:00    4887
26  None    294.31  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    03-10-2012 14:00    5337
27  None    295.17  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    03-10-2012 15:00    5692
28  None    295.13  0.00    0.0 1   Clear   sky is clear    03-10-2012 16:00    6137
29  None    293.66  0.00    0.0 20  Clouds  few clouds  03-10-2012 18:00    4623
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
48174   None    280.55  0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 29-09-2018 20:00    3338
48175   None    280.4   0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 29-09-2018 21:00    2950
48176   None    280.54  0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 29-09-2018 22:00    2607
48177   None    280.32  0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 29-09-2018 23:00    3856
48178   None    280.3   0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 30-09-2018 00:00    1826
48179   None    280.19  0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 30-09-2018 01:00    920
48180   None    280.07  0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 30-09-2018 02:00    696
48181   None    280.08  0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 30-09-2018 03:00    364
48182   None    279.88  0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 30-09-2018 04:00    335
48183   None    279.96  0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 30-09-2018 05:00    444
48184   None    280.17  0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 30-09-2018 06:00    802
48185   None    280.16  0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 30-09-2018 07:00    1175
48186   None    280.28  0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 30-09-2018 08:00    2002
48187   None    280.62  0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 30-09-2018 09:00    2882
48188   None    281.38  0.00    0.0 75  Clouds  broken clouds   30-09-2018 10:00    3701
48189   None    282.18  0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 30-09-2018 11:00    4049
48190   None    282.69  0.00    0.0 75  Clouds  broken clouds   30-09-2018 12:00    4429
48191   None    283.03  0.00    0.0 90  Rain    light rain  30-09-2018 13:00    4547
48192   None    283.48  0.00    0.0 90  Rain    light rain  30-09-2018 14:00    4380
48193   None    283.48  0.00    0.0 90  Drizzle light intensity drizzle 30-09-2018 14:00    4380
48194   None    283.84  0.00    0.0 75  Rain    proximity shower rain   30-09-2018 15:00    4302
48195   None    283.84  0.00    0.0 75  Drizzle light intensity drizzle 30-09-2018 15:00    4302
48196   None    284.38  0.00    0.0 75  Rain    light rain  30-09-2018 16:00    4283
48197   None    284.79  0.00    0.0 75  Clouds  broken clouds   30-09-2018 17:00    4132
48198   None    284.2   0.25    0.0 75  Rain    light rain  30-09-2018 18:00    3947
48199   None    283.45  0.00    0.0 75  Clouds  broken clouds   30-09-2018 19:00    3543
48200   None    282.76  0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 30-09-2018 20:00    2781
48201   None    282.73  0.00    0.0 90  Thunderstorm    proximity thunderstorm  30-09-2018 21:00    2159
48202   None    282.09  0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 30-09-2018 22:00    1450
48203   None    282.12  0.00    0.0 90  Clouds  overcast clouds 30-09-2018 23:00    954
48204 rows × 9 columns

X = file.iloc[:, 0:8].values
X
array([['None', '288.28', 0.0, ..., 'Clouds', 'scattered clouds',
        '02-10-2012 09:00'],
       ['None', '289.36', 0.0, ..., 'Clouds', 'broken clouds',
        '02-10-2012 10:00'],
       ['None', '289.58', 0.0, ..., 'Clouds', 'overcast clouds',
        '02-10-2012 11:00'],
       ...,
       ['None', '282.73', 0.0, ..., 'Thunderstorm',
        'proximity thunderstorm', '30-09-2018 21:00'],
       ['None', '282.09', 0.0, ..., 'Clouds', 'overcast clouds',
        '30-09-2018 22:00'],
       ['None', '282.12', 0.0, ..., 'Clouds', 'overcast clouds',
        '30-09-2018 23:00']], dtype=object)
y = file.iloc[:,8].values
y
array([5545, 4516, 4767, ..., 2159, 1450,  954], dtype=int64)
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
Imputer?
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean')
X[:,1:2] = imputer.fit_transform(X[:,1:2])
```

---

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-16df31c15042> in <module>
----> 1 X[:,1:2] = imputer.fit_transform(X[:,1:2])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    462         if y is None:
    463             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 464             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    465         else:
    466             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\impute.py in fit(self, X, y)
    221         self : SimpleImputer
    222         """
--> 223         X = self._validate_input(X)
    224 
    225         # default fill_value is 0 for numerical input and "missing_value"

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\impute.py in _validate_input(self, X)
    195                                  "".format(self.strategy, X.dtype.kind))
    196             else:
--> 197                 raise ve
    198 
    199         _check_inputs_dtype(X, self.missing_values)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\impute.py in _validate_input(self, X)
    188         try:
    189             X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csc', dtype=dtype,
--> 190                             force_all_finite=force_all_finite, copy=self.copy)
    191         except ValueError as ve:
    192             if "could not convert" in str(ve):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    571         if force_all_finite:
    572             _assert_all_finite(array,
--> 573                                allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
    574 
    575     shape_repr = _shape_repr(array.shape)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan)
     54                 not allow_nan and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
     55             type_err = 'infinity' if allow_nan else 'NaN, infinity'
---> 56             raise ValueError(msg_err.format(type_err, X.dtype))
     57 
     58 

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Comment: your post is a mess. Please make sure you format posts in a good way so that it is readable. This increases the chance for good answers. The problem is quite verbose: „ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')„. You seem to have missing values in your DF.